# Assume $f(x)$ has continuous derivative on $[0,1]$ ,$|f'(x)| \leq M$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Assume $f(x)$ has continuous derivative on $[0,1]$ with $|f'(x)| \leq M$ and
$f(0)=f(1)=0$.

Prove that 
$$\left| \int_0^1 f(x) \ dx \right| \leq \frac{M}{4}$$

Comment: what are your thoughts?

Comment: I use differential mean-value thm to f(x) at x=0 and x=1 respectively and spilt the interval [0,1] into two parts,and then integral.But it seems to cannot get the result

Comment: Hint: Consider $\int_0^{1/2}$ and $\int_{1/2}^1$ separately.

Answer (score 2):

A hint: Try to imagine how fast $f$ can grow from the ends towards the center of the interval.

By the way, you can replace $\leq$ by $<$ in the claim.

Comment: But the strict inequality is harder to prove!

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(x)$ is differentiable on $I=(0,1/2]$ and $f(0)=0$,
$$g(x)\triangleq \frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$
is a continuous function on $I$, bounded by $M$ by Lagrange's theorem. This gives:
$$ \int_{0}^{1/2} f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1/2}x\,g(x)\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{1/2} Mx\,dx = \frac{M}{8}, $$
hence the claim.

Comment: @user46944: ok, good point. Anyway, it is sufficient to remove the point $x=0$ from $I$, now fixed.

Comment: Ok, I removed my last comment.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Let $g(x)=x-a$ where $a=\frac{3 + \sqrt{6}}{6}$. Using the Cauchy Inequality
$$ \left(\int_0^1f'(x)g(x)dx\right)^2\le\int_0^1(f'(x))^2dx\int_0^1(g(x))^2dx $$
I think you will get the desired inequality. Note that
$$ \int_0^1(x-a)^2dx=\frac{1}{4}, \int_0^1(x-a)f'(x)dx=-\int_0^1f(x)dx. $$

Comment: What does this have to do with his question?

Comment: @Zarrax, you have to use the integration-by-parts formula.